# AsyncTask isn't async?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-asynctask

Somehow I cant use the GUI before the AsyncTask finished. I didn't recognize any difference between posting the execute() in "onCreate" or "onCreateOptionsMenu" method.
Do you know what's wrong?
Thanks for any help.

```
package com.test11;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class TestActitivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_actitivity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_test_actitivity, menu);

        try
        {
            int t = new TestTask().execute().get();
        }

        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (ExecutionException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }

    class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
    {
        public Integer doInBackground(Void...voids)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make `TestTask` a `public static class` or move it out into it's own `class`, for a start.

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-seperate-asynctask-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You execute your task like this:

```
new TestTask().execute().get();
```

What do you do exactly here? You create a new task instance. Then you run it. And then you call `get()` on your task, which [waits until the computation of this task is completed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) to return it's value. Which means that `onCreate()` or `onCreateOptionsMenu()` are blocked until the second thread is finished. If you remove `get()`, your task won't block the UI.

If you want to work with your result, you should override [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) in your AsyncTask instead of using `get()`. `onPostExecute()` runs in the UI thread and allows you to use the result to manipulate the UI easily. If you want to display your result in a textview for example, you would use an implementation like this:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampletext);
    tv.setText("Result was " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs for [`get`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29):

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

You almost never need to call that method on an `AsyncTask`. Just call `execute`.

Comment: Thx that was the problem, but how can i get the return of the AsyncTask now?

Comment: You do any processing you need to do in terms of the results in [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29)